# $V$ is the space of sequences in $\mathbb{F}$ with finitely many nonzero terms. Show $\varphi$ is unbounded when $V$ has norm $\|\{a_k\}\|=\max|a_k|$.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, continuity, linear-transformations, normed-spaces

I'm studying for my Real Analysis exam coming up, and I'm looking at the second bullet point in Example 6.50 from [*Measure, Integration, and Real Analysis* by Sheldon Axler](https://measure.axler.net/). This is quoted below (note that Axler uses $\mathbb{F}$ to mean either $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$):

> Let $V$ be the vector space of sequences $(a_1,a_2,\dots)$ of elements of $\mathbb{F}$ such that $a_k=0$ for all but finitely many $k\in\mathbb{Z}^+.$ Define $\varphi:V\to\mathbb{F}$ by $\varphi(a_1,a_2,\dots) = \sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k.$ Then $\varphi$ is a linear functional on $V$. If we make $V$ a normed vector space with the norm $\|(a_1,a_2,\dots)\|_\infty=\max_{k\in\mathbb{Z}^+}|a_k|$, then $\varphi$ is not a bounded linear functional on $V$, as you should verify.

I'm attempting to verify this and I am wondering if my verification is correct. Here's what I did:

To see $\varphi$ is not bounded, consider the sequence $\{v_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ in $V$ where $v_n=(\underbrace{1,1,\dots,1}_{\text{first $n$ terms}},0,0,\dots)$ for each $n\in\mathbb{Z}^+$. Note that $\|v_n\|_\infty = 1$ and $\varphi(v_n)=n$ for each $n\in\mathbb{Z}^+$. Thus it's easy to see that $|\varphi(v_n)|\to\infty$ as $n\to\infty$, which shows $\varphi$ is unbounded.

Is this correct?

Comment: yes, it seems correct.

Answer (score 1):

Seems correct. Since $v_n \in V$, $||v_n|| = 1$ for all $n$ and

$$\forall N \in \mathbb{Z}^+, |\varphi(v_{N+1})| = N + 1 > N = N\, ||v_n||, $$

$\varphi$ is unbounded.